# MVVMCross changing ViewModel within a MvxBindableListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, viewmodel, mvvmcross

Little problem with my Android application and I don't know how to solve it with MVVM Cross.

Here is my Model

```
public class Article 
{
    string Label{ get; set; }
    string Remark { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel

```
public class ArticleViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    public List<Article> Articles;
    ....

}
```

My layout.axml
    ...

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutArticleList">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editSearch"
            android:text=""
            android:singleLine="True"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:capitalize="characters"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_24"
            local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Filter','Mode':'TwoWay'}}"
            />
      <Mvx.MvxBindableListView
            android:id="@+id/listviewArticle"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/article_rowlayout"
            local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Articles'}}" />                
    </LinearLayout>
...
```

And here comes my problem, the "article_rowlayout"

```
...
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowArticleLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="14"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28dip"
            local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Label'}}" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_modify"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rowArticleButtonModify"
            android:background="@null" 
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true"    
            local:MvxBind="{'Click':{'Path':'MyTest'}}"
          />
...
```

The "Click" command called "MyTest" is linked on the item given by the MvxBindableListView.  In other words, Click search for a command "MyTest" in my model "Article", instead of my ViewModel.  How can I change that behaviour in order to link my ViewModel "ArticleViewModel" which is responsible of my MvxBindableListView?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your analysis is definitely correct about where the click event is trying to bind.

There are two approaches I generally take:

1. Use ItemClick on the List
2. Continuing using Click but do some redirection on the ViewModel side.

---

So...1

The [Main Menu](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20Tutorial/Tutorial/Tutorial.Core/ViewModels/MainMenuViewModel.cs) in the tutorial has a ViewModel a bit like:

```
public class MainMenuViewModel
    : MvxViewModel
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    public IMvxCommand ShowItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxRelayCommand<T>((item) => /* do action with item */ );
        }
    }
}
```

This is used in axml as:

```
<Mvx.MvxBindableListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Tutorial.UI.Droid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Items'},'ItemClick':{'Path':'ShowItemCommand'}}"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_viewmodel"
  />
```

This approach can only be done for ItemClick on the whole list item - not on individual subviews within the list items.

---

Or...2

Since we don't have any `RelativeSource` binding instructions in mvx, this type of redirection can be done in the ViewModel/Model code.

This can be done by presenting a behaviour-enabled wrapper of the Model object rather than the Model object itself - e.g. using a `List<ActiveArticle>`:

```
public ActiveArticle
{
   Article _article;
   ArticleViewModel _parent;

   public WrappedArticle(Article article, ArticleViewModel parent)
   {
       /* assignment */
   }

   public IMvxCommand TheCommand { get { return MvxRelayCommand(() -> _parent.DoStuff(_article)); } }

   public Article TheArticle { get { return _article; } } 
}
```

Your axml would then have to use bindings like:

```
    <TextView            ...
        local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'TheArticle.Label'}}" />
```

and

```
    <ImageButton
        ...
        local:MvxBind="{'Click':{'Path':'TheCommand.MyTest'}}" />
```

One example of this approach is the Conference sample which uses [WithCommand](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.Core/ViewModels/Helpers/WithCommand.cs)

However... please note that when using `WithCommand<T>` we discovered a memory leak - basically the GarbageCollection refused to collect the embedded `MvxRelayCommand` - which is why `WithCommand<T>` is `IDisposable` and why [BaseSessionListViewModel](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.Core/ViewModels/SessionLists/BaseSessionListViewModel.cs) clears the list and disposes the WithCommand elements when views are detached.

---

**Update after comment:**

If your data list is large - and your data is fixed (your articles are models without PropertyChanged) and you don't want to incur the overhead of creating a large `List<WrappedArticle>` then one way around this might be to use a `WrappingList<T>` class.

This is very similar to the approach taken in Microsoft code - e.g. in virtualizing lists in WP7/Silverlight - http://shawnoster.com/blog/post/Improving-ListBox-Performance-in-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-7-Data-Virtualization.aspx

For your articles this might be:

```
public class ArticleViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    public WrappingList<Article> Articles;

    // normal members...
}

public class Article
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Remark { get; set; }
}

public class WrappingList<T> : IList<WrappingList<T>.Wrapped>
{
    public class Wrapped
    {
        public IMvxCommand Command1 { get; set; }
        public IMvxCommand Command2 { get; set; }
        public IMvxCommand Command3 { get; set; }
        public IMvxCommand Command4 { get; set; }
        public T TheItem { get; set; }
    }

    private readonly List<T> _realList;
    private readonly Action<T>[] _realAction1;
    private readonly Action<T>[] _realAction2;
    private readonly Action<T>[] _realAction3;
    private readonly Action<T>[] _realAction4;

    public WrappingList(List<T> realList, Action<T> realAction)
    {
        _realList = realList;
        _realAction = realAction;
    }

    private Wrapped Wrap(T item)
    {
        return new Wrapped()
            {
                Command1 = new MvxRelayCommand(() => _realAction1(item)),
                Command2 = new MvxRelayCommand(() => _realAction2(item)),
                Command3 = new MvxRelayCommand(() => _realAction3(item)),
                Command4 = new MvxRelayCommand(() => _realAction4(item)),
                TheItem = item
            };
    }

    #region Implementation of Key required methods

    public int Count { get { return _realList.Count; } }

    public Wrapped this[int index]
    {
        get { return Wrap(_realList[index]); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region NonImplementation of other methods

    public IEnumerator<Wrapped> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(Wrapped item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(Wrapped item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(Wrapped[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(Wrapped item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IList<DateFilter>

    public int IndexOf(Wrapped item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(int index, Wrapped item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: In fact, I have 4 imagebuttons with behaviour on my listview. So the first solution is impossible.  For the second one, my problem is that I reveice my list from another framework (vici coolstorage), and parsing the whole list to create a new one with "ActiveArticle" will put a serious overhead (I can have several thousand of items).  But anyway, I will try this solution and let you know if it works. By the way, don't you think it will be difficult to create a "RelativeSource" on your framework? Thanks!

Comment: Have added an alternative for you - see update in the answer. For "By the way, don't you think it will be difficult" it would require some way of identifying the relativesource on all platforms (e.g. it might have to use some way of navigating the parent hierarchy in Droid) and then identifying what property to bind to (Droid native view's don't have a convenient DataContext DependencyObject). It could be possible - would be interested to see what you'd like - feel free to draft what your ideal axml solution might look like as an issue in github/slodge/mvvmcross

Comment: Hi Stuart, you new solution is THE solution for me. Thanks a lot. I put your solution in my code, and I will put the "ideal axml vision" (for me) as an issue in github. Thank again, your are great!

Comment: Great answer! I have just small question about solution 2: What are the benefits of using `WrappedArticle` instead just `Article` with `ICommand` property? Is it supposed to make  Article model "cleaner" and seperate behavior from model itself or are there any other benefits?

Comment: It's just code - and assumes `Article` already exists (e.g. from a JSON or SQL code generator)

Comment: @Stuart I'm trying the same in ListItemtemplate based on above code local:MvxBind="Click OnRemoveClick, CommandParameter=." I'm getting the same "." while executing commmand. any idea please?

Comment: @Stuart Any updates on the best way to do this? similar issue, i have a recycler view and i want the individual items in the recycler view to be clickable