# MvvmCross vnext: monodroid binding Dictionary Key similar to wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

When I change MainMenuViewModel in Tutorial.Core to use a Dictionary like this:

`public Dictionary Items { get; set; }
    public ICommand ShowItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxRelayCommand>((type) => DoShowItem(type.Value));
        }
    }

```
public void DoShowItem(Type itemType)
{
    this.RequestNavigate(itemType);
}

public MainMenuViewModel()
{
    Items = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
                {
                    {"SimpleTextProperty",  typeof(Lessons.SimpleTextPropertyViewModel)},
                    {"PullToRefresh",  typeof(Lessons.PullToRefreshViewModel)},
                    {"Tip",  typeof(Lessons.TipViewModel)},
                    {"Composite",typeof(Lessons.CompositeViewModel)},
                    {"Location",typeof(Lessons.LocationViewModel)}
                };
}`
```

The sample is working as expected in wp7, but with monodroid I get an error::"MvxBind:Error: 2,71 Problem seen during binding execution for from Items to ItemsSource - problem ArgumentException: failed to convert parameters" because I think KeyValuePair Key property causes the problem in:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Tutorial.UI.Droid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="View Model:"
        />
  <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Key'}}"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the mvxbindablelistview expects an object that supports the IList interface - so it can't currently bind to a Dictionary.

This is what 'ArgumentException: failed to convert parameters' tells us.

---

If you want to use a dictionary, then you could apply a converter that maps the dictionary to a List()

---

If you  think this is a missing feature in mvx - if you feel lists should bind to any ienumerable (or maybe to any icollection), then please log this is an issue on github.

---

**Update** - this has been pursued on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/38 - and the behavior is now changed.

Comment: Ok, I understand the error now. So I bypass the problem using List<KeyValuePair<string,Type>> instead of Dictionary<string,Type>.

Comment: Yes - just been looking at this. The motivation for not supporting icollection and ienumerable seems good - basically ilist adds operator[] indexed access which allows the listview to operate more efficiently than using ienumerable. We could add ienumerable support, and it would allow better compliance with wp7, but it would lead to inefficient listviews.