# MvvmCross Android - Alternative to RelativeSource binding for button command

Tags: android, binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a list of items bound to a MvxBindableListView with a MvxItemTemplate.
I usually have 4 items in my list bound to my view. Data gets updated and the view displays the new data just fine[image].

Now, I want to add two buttons to this item template. However, relative source binding is not available with MvvmCross. (see image)

But I'm having difficulties working out a solution to this.

I have tried the ItemClick binding of the list item, but that only gives me 1 possibility of click and I need 2.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the second option in the answer in [MVVMCross changing ViewModel within a MvxBindableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682082/mvvmcross-changing-viewmodel-within-a-mvxbindablelistview) - this covers one way to do this.

Using that approach you'd expose a list of objects like:

```
public class Wrapped
{
    public ICommand GoThruCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand OpenCommand { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and you'd use an axml list template with bound controls like:

```
<TextView
    ...
    local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Name'}}" />

<Button
    ...
    local:MvxBind="{'Click':{'Path':'GoCommand'}}" />    

<Button
    ...
    local:MvxBind="{'Click':{'Path':'ThruCommand'}}" />
```

---

if you've got suggestions/requests for relative source in mvx, please add them to https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/35

Comment: I saw this article before, but I cannot get my head around option 2, do you have a concrete example by any chance

Comment: not other than the stuff already referenced in that question.

Comment: Hi Stuart, I found out that this solution is not actually working when deploying the application in Release. Would you know why?

Comment: Comments are not the place for new questions

Comment: Ok fair enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291696/mvvmcross-android-button-click-binding-not-working-in-release-build