# Binding to Parent and Grandparent?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How would I bind to a grandparent in MVVMCross?

I have a `List<string>` which I'm binding to a `MvxLinearLayout` with its own item template "A". When the user clicks on the button in "A" I would like to fire an `ICommand` in its parent (i.e. the owner of the `List<string>`).

I also have a similar situation with a grandparent relation.

How would I do this?

Comment: Also other questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208203/mvvmcross-android-alternative-to-relativesource-binding-for-button-command/14210232

Comment: Yes, I could do it like that. I was just hoping to avoid having to create a ViewModel wrapper around string.

Answer (score 0):

There is no parent binding access in lists or any other mvx data binding context currently.

There are plenty of simple workarounds - see questions such as [MvvmCross Android - Alternative to RelativeSource binding for button command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208203/mvvmcross-android-alternative-to-relativesource-binding-for-button-command/14210232) for some suggestions.

---

I've answered questions similar to this several times. Each time i invite people to raise feature requests, ideas or pulls to issues such as https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/35 . While there have been perhaps 3 or 4 of these questions, no-one ever seems bothered enough to follow up, so i guess it's not an important feature.