# ListBoxItem with ContextMenu item to Command

Tags: binding, contextmenu, windows-phone, mvvmcross

I'm using a ContextMenu from the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

And want to delete a ListBoxItem via a DeleteCommand

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu >
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="????"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

DeleteCommand:

```
public ICommand DeleteCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand<BulbItem>(item =>
        {
            _collectionService.Delete(item);
            Close(this);
        });
    }
}
```

How do I pass a ListBoxItem that is bound to a list of BulbItems into the DeleteCommand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you **might** be able to just replace `????` with `{Binding}` - in which case the Path is an implicit binding to the object in the `DataContext` itself

---

Beyond that, you'll also need to route the `DeleteCommand` binding to the parent object's DataContext - I think you can do that using some kind of `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` binding - but I'm not an expert on this.

Generally what I do is to put my commands inside my list item objects - e.g. see some of the answer in [MVVMCross changing ViewModel within a MvxBindableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682082/mvvmcross-changing-viewmodel-within-a-mvxbindablelistview/12685784#12685784)

Comment: Now I get a "DeleteCommand" property not found on "Bulb.Core.Services.DataStore.BulbItem", the ICommand is places in the HomeViewModel

Comment: <ListBox **Name="MyListBox"** ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"> and <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding **Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=MyListBox**}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" /> Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the action to execute on `Click event` or `Tap event`?
Something like this:

```
<toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete"  Click="deleteMenu_Click"/>
```

**OR**

```
<toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete"  Tap="deleteMenu_Tap"/>
```

And in the code behind add your delete List item code.