# Binding to IEnumerable rather than IList this can be inefficient - how inefficient it is?

Tags: mvvmcross

In order to find walk-around for absence RelativeSource in MvvmCross, I used Stuart's suggestion and implemented WrappingList
[MVVMCross changing ViewModel within a MvxBindableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682082/mvvmcross-changing-viewmodel-within-a-mvxbindablelistview)

However, I see this trace every bind it happens and I wonder, how worse it is:

> Binding to IEnumerable rather than IList - this can be inefficient,
>   especially for large lists

Maybe there are any other suggestions?

```
   public class WrappingCommandsList<T> : IList<WrappingCommandsList<T>.Wrapped>
{
    private readonly List<T> _realList;
    private readonly Action<T> _realActionOnClick;

    public class Wrapped 
    {
        public IMvxCommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
        public T TheItem { get; set; }
    }

    public WrappingCommandsList(List<T> realList, Action<T> realActionOnClick)
    {
        _realList = realList;
        _realActionOnClick = realActionOnClick;
    }

    private Wrapped Wrap(T item)
    {
        return new Wrapped()
        {
            ClickCommand = new MvxCommand(() => _realActionOnClick(item)),
            TheItem = item
        };
    }

    public WrappingCommandsList<T>.Wrapped this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return Wrap(_realList[index]);
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _realList.Count; }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<WrappingCommandsList<T>.Wrapped> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in _realList)
        {
            yield return Wrap(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How inefficient depends on the length of your list and how far down it the used has scrolled.

eg if the user is showing item 93,256 on the screen then the only way for the list adapter to find item 93,256 is to get the enumerator and to call MoveNext 93,256 times.

Whereas if your list only has 5 items the problem is bounded by 5.

For your particular `WrappingCommandsList` try implementing `IList` as well as `IList<T>` - the mvx code can't generate the `IList<T>` accessors at runtime because of xamarin.ios AoT compilation restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, Stuart!
I hope one day support for RelativeSource will come