# Binding button click in ListView template MvvMCross

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I have a listview with a template containing a button. When the button get's clicked i want an event to fire and return me a value of the listview row, so i can use it to add it to a database. My problem is, i don't know how to bind my buttonevent to the itemtemplate. I've tried a few approaches but with no success so far.

**My Listview:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Mvx.MvxListView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:divider="#aeaeae"

        android:dividerHeight="1px"

        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MenuCollection; ItemClick OrderBtnClick"        

        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_menuitem" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My ItemTemplate:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Mvx.MvxImageView

        android:layout_width="100dp"

        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:layout_margin="10dp"

        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ImageUrl" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"

            android:textSize="40dp"

            local:MvxBind="Text Name" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"

            android:textSize="20dp"

            local:MvxBind="Text ShortDescription" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:minWidth="25px"

        android:minHeight="25px">

        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="70dip"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"

            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"

            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"

            android:text="Bestel"            

            android:id="@+id/button1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
public class ListPresentationViewModel: MvxViewModel    
    {    
        private readonly ISQLService _sqlSvc;   

        public ListPresentationViewModel (ISQLService sqlService)    
        {    
            _sqlSvc = sqlService;    
            MenuCollection = _sqlSvc.MenuItemGetAll ();    
        }   


        private List<MenuItem> _menuCollection = new List<MenuItem> ();    

        public List<MenuItem> MenuCollection {    
            get{ return _menuCollection;}    
            set {    
                _menuCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged (() => MenuCollection);    
            }    
        }    


        private IMvxCommand _orderBtnClick;    
        public IMvxCommand OrderBtnClick{    
            get{    
                _orderBtnClick = _orderBtnClick ?? new MvxCommand(btnClick);

                return _orderBtnClick;}    

        }  


        private void btnClick()    
        {    
            //Do Something    
        }

    }
```

I placed the local:MvxBind="Click OrderBtnClick" on the button in the template and on the listview. The ItemClick seems to work when i remove the button from the itemtemplate, but that's not what i'm looking for. I want the button to be triggering the event. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

***UPDATE*:**

I've tried the second suggestion stuart lodge posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682082/mvvmcross-changing-viewmodel-within-a-mvxbindablelistview). Here is my **wrapper class**:

```
public class MenuItemWrap
    {
        MenuItem _mnuItem;
        ListPresentationViewModel _parent;


        public MenuItemWrap ()
        {           

        }

        public MenuItemWrap (MenuItem item, ListPresentationViewModel parent)
        {
            _mnuItem = item;
            _parent = parent;
        }

        public IMvxCommand Click {
            get {
                return new MvxRelayCommand (() => _parent.btnClick(WrapConverter.ConvertToWrapMenuItem(_mnuItem, _parent)));
            }
        }
        public MenuItem Item{ get { return _mnuItem; } }

    }
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
public class ListPresentationViewModel: MvxViewModel
    {
        private readonly ISQLService _sqlSvc;

        public ListPresentationViewModel (ISQLService sqlService)
        {
            _sqlSvc = sqlService;
            MenuCollection = WrapConverter.ConvertToWrapperClass(_sqlSvc.MenuItemGetAll (), this);
        }

        private List<MenuItemWrap> _menuCollection = new List<MenuItemWrap> ();
        public List<MenuItemWrap> MenuCollection {
            get{ return _menuCollection;}
            set {
                _menuCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged (() => MenuCollection);
            }
        }

        private IMvxCommand _orderBtnClick;
        public IMvxCommand OrderBtnClick{
            get{
                _orderBtnClick = _orderBtnClick ?? new MvxCommand<MenuItemWrap> (btnClick);
                return _orderBtnClick;
            }
        }

        public void btnClick(MenuItemWrap item)
        {
            MenuCollection.Clear ();
        }
    }
```

And here is my **template**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Mvx.MvxImageView

        android:layout_width="100dp"

        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:layout_margin="10dp"

        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Item.ImageUrl" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"

            android:textSize="40dp"

            local:MvxBind="Text Item.Name" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"

            android:textSize="20dp"

            local:MvxBind="Text Item.ShortDescription" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:minWidth="25px"

        android:minHeight="25px">

        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="70dip"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"

            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"

            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"

            android:text="Bestel"

            local:MvxBind="Click btnClick.OrderBtnClick"

            android:id="@+id/button1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My listview works perfectly. All properties get bind correctly, and i can see the name, shortdescription and image. What does not work is the Button Click. In my application output i get an error saying: *MvxBind:Warning: 76.06 Unable to bind: source property source not found Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken on MenuItemWrap*

I've tried a few approaches to fix it, but with no success. I will mention i did not find the RelayCommand class in the MvvMCross assemblies so i copy pasted the code from [here](https://github.com/slodge/MonoCrossExtensions/blob/master/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Commands/MvxRelayCommand.cs) into my project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682082/mvvmcross-changing-viewmodel-within-a-mvxbindablelistview - old version of mvx but the approach should work

Comment: Thank you verry much Stuart! I looked around but did not found this post. It seems to be just what i was looking for.

Comment: @Stuart I've updated my questions. Would you mind taking a quick look? I would be verry grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution. The problem was the click binding. You should only refer to the action in the wrapper class and not both. Here are my wrapperclass & listview itemtemplate.

**ItemTemplate:**

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:text="Bestel"
                local:MvxBind="Click OrderClick" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

**WrapperClass:**

```
public class MenuItemWrap
    {
        MenuItem _mnuItem;
        ListPresentationViewModel _parent;      

        public MenuItemWrap (MenuItem item, ListPresentationViewModel parent)
        {
            _mnuItem = item;
            _parent = parent;
        }


        public IMvxCommand OrderClick {
            get {
                return new MvxCommand (() => _parent.btnClick (_mnuItem));
            }
        }

        public MenuItem Item{ get { return _mnuItem; } }    
    }
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
public class ListPresentationViewModel: MvxViewModel 
{
    private readonly ISQLService _sqlSvc;

    public ListPresentationViewModel (ISQLService sqlService)
    {
        _sqlSvc = sqlService;
        MenuCollection = WrapConverter.ConvertToWrapperClass (_sqlSvc.MenuItemGetAll(), this);
    }

    private int _catId;
    public int CategorieId { 
        get{ return _catId;} 
        set{ 
            _catId = value;
            ChangeMenuCollection ();
        }
    }

    private void ChangeMenuCollection()
    {
        MenuCollection = WrapConverter.ConvertToWrapperClass (_sqlSvc.MenuItemByCategorie (_catId), this);
    }

    private List<MenuItemWrap> _menuCollection = new List<MenuItemWrap> ();
    public List<MenuItemWrap> MenuCollection {
        get{ return _menuCollection;}
        set {
            _menuCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => MenuCollection);
        }
    }

    private IMvxCommand _orderBtnClick;

    public IMvxCommand OrderBtnClick {
        get {
            _orderBtnClick = _orderBtnClick ?? new MvxCommand<MenuItem> (btnClick);
            return _orderBtnClick;
        }
    }

    public void btnClick (MenuItem item)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Nicely written.

Comment: what's WrapConverter.ConvertToWrapperClass ? can you share this?

Answer (score 1):

1. `MvxRelayCommand` in vNext got shortened to `MvxCommand` in v3 - just to save typing.
2. Your last problem seems to be that you are binding `Click btnClick.OrderBtnClick` - but your `MenuItemWrap` class doesn't have a `btnClick` property - so you actually want to bind `Click Click` ?

Comment: I changed my command in the MenuItemWrap class like this:
public IMvxCommand OrderClick {
   get {
    return new MvxCommand (() => _parent.btnClick ());
   }
  }

And the Click command in the view like this:

local:MvxBind="Click OrderClick.OrderBtnClick"

But i still get the error "MvxBind:Warning: 20.65 Unable to bind: source property source not found Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken on MvxCommand". I'm a little clueless right now to what is causing this... :(

Comment: whats better, this approach, or the IMvxMessenger approach mentioned here https://github.com/kiliman/MvxCommandToMessage