# Button click in ListItem of Listview using Icommand

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have **Listitems** with delete button in **MvxListView**.I want to delete perticular row in which delete button is clicked.How to implement that click event using **Icommand**?

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535943/bind-button-click-inside-customlayout-using-mvvmcross-and-mvxlistview/23550438#23550438

Answer (score 0):

Extend the `MvxListView` to have a `DeleteClick` property:

`ICommand DeleteClik;`

Bind this property to the command you want:

```
local:MvxBind="DeleteClick MyDeleteCommand"
```

Create a custom adapter that'll have a reference to this `DeleteClick` command and bind it to your view's click event on the `GetView` method:

```
public override View GetView (int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //TODO: Ensure view is not null, call base method and convert to proper type
    var deleteButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonId);

    deleteButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
        if(_deleteCommand != null && _deleteCommand.CanExecute()) 
        {
            //TODO: Cast to your type
            _deleteCommand(GetRawItem(position));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more precise? because I have the same problem and I don't understand your answer..