# MvxListView - button inside template

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have created MvxListView in Android. I am binding it to ObservableCollection.

Everything is working fine. Even SelectedItem Command fires correctly. The problem is when I add button inside each item.

My list contains images with buttons to remove each other.

There is `item_photo.axml`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/icons"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/DepartureDateTitleTextView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      local:MvxBind="Text Comment"
      android:textColor="@color/primary"
      android:textSize="17dp" />
  <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxBind="Bitmap NativeReference, Converter=ObjectToBitmap, FallbackValue=''"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/titleLinearLayout"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/icons"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/PriceTextView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Remove"
      android:textColor="@color/accent"
      android:textSize="17dp"
      local:MvxBind="Click RemoveCommand" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is really stranbe because Photo and Comment properties are binding.

```
public MvxCommand RemoveCommand { get; set; }
```

However RemoveCommand doesnt fires. Any ideas?

EDIT:

When I add Command to my model its working thats why properties are binding. How then I can achive event in ViewModel not Model ?

In XAML I could bind ancestors` data context is it possible there?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's a limitation of MvvmCross. The MvxListView doesn't support binding to its parent ViewModel.

I even posted a possible solution which uses the Messenger plugin to communicate with the parent VM. [Bind button click inside customlayout using mvvmcross and mvxlistview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535943/bind-button-click-inside-customlayout-using-mvvmcross-and-mvxlistview/23550438#23550438)

However, lately I simply create a wrapper ViewModel for my listview items, and put all my logic in there. If I need access to the parent, I simply add a property for that in my wrapper VM.

Something like:

```
public class PhotoViewModel {
   public SomeViewModel ParentViewModel { get; set; }
   public PhotoModel Photo { get; set; }
   public ICommand RemovePhotoCommand {
      get {
          return new MvxCommand(() => {
              ParentViewModel.RemovePhotoCommand.Execute(this);
          });
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created custom wrapper for this problem:

```
   public class CommandableCollectionItem<TItem, TViewModel>
                            where TViewModel : ICommandableNestedCollection<TItem>
    {
        public TItem Item { get; private set; }
        private readonly TViewModel _viewModel;

        public CommandableCollectionItem(TItem item, TViewModel viewModel)
        {
            this.Item = item;
            this._viewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public IMvxCommand Execute => new MvxCommand(() => _viewModel.OnExecute(Item));

    }


public interface ICommandableNestedCollection<T>
    {
        void OnExecute<T>(T item);
    }
```

So ViewModel implements ICommandableNestedCollection interface where T is Item

```
MyViewModel : ICommandableNestedCollection<TakenPhotoModel>
{
  public void OnExecute<T>(T item)
  {
     //code
  }
}
```