# Mvvm cross binding data context

Tags: android, data-binding, mvvmcross

I am trying to implement a mvvm cross solution. I am facing an issue with bindings..

I am trying to implement the solution in xamarin.android.

Below is my Main Layout page - Main.axml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        local:MvxBind="Text Title/>
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/SRMTypeList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/list_Item"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource PersonCollection" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my View Model:

```
public class MainViewModel :MvxViewModel
{
    private string title;

    public String Title
    {
        get{ return title;}
        set
        {
            title = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged (()=> Title);
        }
    }

    List<Person> _personCollection;       
    List<Person> PersonCollection
    {
        get { return _personCollection; }
        set
        { 
           _personCollection = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged (() => PersonCollection);
        }

    public MainViewModel()
    { 
        _personCollection = new List<Person>();
        PersonCollection.Add(new Person{Name="Steve", Salary=10000});
        PersonCollection.Add(new Person{Name="Mary", Salary=20000});
    }
}
```

MainView.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
     base.OnCreate (bundle);
     SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
}
```

The issue starts here in the item template for my list view in the main screen    list_Item.axml is shown below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="?" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        local:MvxBind="?"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How to make the binding for TextView's Text and CheckBox to parent's view model (ie. in the Main View Model class)?.

Any pointer/ help to solve this will be highly appreciated.

I have gone through below links .. but being a newbie was not able to understand the implementation.

[Binding button click in ListView template MvvMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075928/binding-button-click-in-listview-template-mvvmcross?lq=1)

[MVVMCross changing ViewModel within a MvxBindableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682082/mvvmcross-changing-viewmodel-within-a-mvxbindablelistview)

I am not able to understand how to create the wrapper class and how to set the data context of the item template (list_Item.axml) to this wrapper class. 
Is their any way in mvvm cross so that i can refer bindings in the item template directly to the parent view model in  my case which is MainViewModel.

Can anyone kindly post a simpler example?
    Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you are asking, but to make a binding of the person's name to the listitem textview:

```
local:MvxBind="Text Name"
```

And instead of using a List you should use an ObservableCollection

```
ObservableCollection<Person> _personCollection;       
ObservableCollection<Person> PersonCollection
{
    get { return _personCollection; }
    set
    { 
       _personCollection = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged (() => PersonCollection);
    }
```

}

For the checkbox i would add a field to the Person class such as IsSelected and bind it to the checkbox:

```
 local:MvxBind="Checked IsSelected"
```